Вывод данных по очереди из БД в таблице JS
у меня есть таблица на скрипте. Там в одном столбике значение online его заменяю на ipi, но на таблице выводит на каждой строке все данные из БД. типа 1.2.3.4.5 и все они в каждой строке, хотя должно было идти по очереди. 1 след строка 2 след строка 3 и т д. как это сделать?
$sql = "SELECT * FROM test";
if($result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql)){
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, 1)
       
    {
   
    
$st = $row[0]['ipi'];


       echo "<script>var online = '$st'</script>";

}}


Во-первых, этот код берет из базы только одну строку. Во-вторых, даже если он будет выбирать все, то с этим кодом он просто перезапишет переменную online последним значением.

и как тогда сделать? просто таблицу саму заполнять?
